# Componente Não é Renderizado Por Ajax

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat

Tenho um formulário, onde internamente possui um componente **h:message** e um **h:inputText**, e estou submetendo este formulário por ajax padrão do jsf... o problema é... ao submeter o formulário o ajax não atualiza os componentes que deveria atualizar no atributo **render**.

Algo que ocorreu foi, que quando eu removo o atributo **execute** do componente **ajax** funciona perfeitamente, mas o formulário não é submetido, a seguir tem o código:

```
<h:form id="questoes_form">
<h:panelGroup id="panel_tabela">
    <h:dataTable  id="table_questoes" binding="#
 {questoesCPA.questoesDataTable}" value="#{questoesCPA.questoesList}" 
var="questao" styleClass="table responsive-table table-striped table-hover">

        <h:column>                                
            <f:facet name="header" >
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selecionarTodos" value="#{questoesCPA.todosSelecionados}" valueChangeListener="#{questoesCPA.selecionadorTodos}" class="checkbox pull-right">
                    <f:ajax execute="selecionarTodos" render="tableQuestoes"/>
                </h:selectBooleanCheckbox></f:facet>

            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="sleci" value="#{questao.selecionado}" valueChangeListener="#{questoesCPA.selecionar}" class="checkbox pull-right">
                <f:ajax execute="sleci" render="tableQuestoes"/>
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

        </h:column>
        <h:column>                             
            <f:facet name="header" >Código</f:facet>
            QCPA#{questao.queId}CX
        </h:column>

        <h:column>                             
            <f:facet name="header" >Data e Horário da Criação</f:facet>
                #{questao.queDataCriacao}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header" >Tipo</f:facet>
                #{questao.queTipoQuestao}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header" >Ação</f:facet>
            <h:commandLink value=" " class="btn btn-default fa fa-pencil" title="Editar" ></h:commandLink>
            <h:commandLink value=" " class="btn btn-default fa fa-trash" style="margin-left: 0.25em;" title="Deletar"></h:commandLink>
            <h:commandLink value=" " class="btn btn-default fa fa-eye" style="margin-left: 0.25em;" title="Respostas"></h:commandLink>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

```
    <h:form id="questoes_subjetivas_form">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Questão Subjetiva</div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label>Enunciado<span class="text-danger bold">*</span></label>                                                    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-6">                                                
                                    <h:inputText id="enunciado_subjetiva" value="#{questaoSubjetivaCPA.questaoSubjetivaCPA.queEnunciado}" required="true" requiredMessage="Este Campo é de Preenchimento Obrigatório" label="Enunciado da Questão" pt:placeholder="Enunciado da Questão" class="form-control"/>
                                    <h:message for="enunciado_subjetiva" class="text-danger row">
                                    </h:message>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8" >

                    <h:commandButton value="Salvar" class="btn btn-primary" action="#{questaoSubjetivaCPA.salvarQuestao}">
                        <f:ajax  render="@form :message_request :questoes_form:panel_tabela"  execute=" @form" >                                                        
                                                </f:ajax>


                    </h:commandButton>

                    <h:commandButton type="reset"  value="Limpar" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-left: 0.6em;">                                                    

                    </h:commandButton>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </h:form>

</div>
```

Comment: No seu botão salvar quais componentes realmente precisam ser atualizados ?

Comment: O próprio formulário, uma mensagem contendo a resposta da ação e uma tabela que contém os dados que foram salvos.